# Use php to get data out of a excel worksheet based on 2 values

Tags: php, excel

i have an excel sheet that looks like this :

```
          vr600    vr700    vr800   vr900    -------length
vr600   65           68       70    73
vr700   68           70       72    76
vr800   71           74       76    80
vr900   73           76       80    81
vr1000  76           79       81    84
vr1100  80           82       85    87
vr1200  82           85       87    91
vr1300  83           86       91    97
vr1400  87           90       97    102
vr1500  90           93       102   108
height
```

now i have a website with 2 combo boxes, (now it just multiplies the 2 values)
http://robabny94.ninetyfour.axc.nl/pechhulp/testprogramma.php
when the length and height in the combo boxes get filled i would like to return the correct value. 
i looked into it if i could figure out some kind of formula to get the numbers but it seems rather random

just cant figure out a way to get this working.

thanks in advance for your help!

edit : if it helps to put the data into mysql or so , that would also be possible

cheers

Comment: Have you tried using `PHPExcel`? Otherwise, putting it into MySQL isn't a bad idea.

Comment: Do you need Excel formula to get you desired number for provided height and length, or.......?

Comment: Well if could somehow return the value of those comboboxes into excel, and then let excel find the value that would do the job i think. Since i can read it out again and show it on the webpage right ? (sorry kinda new to php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at all familiar with PHP, but In case you may read / write via PHP from Excel - the following formula will provide you the desired result based on Height and Length input (assuming the structure in your initial input):

`=INDEX($B$2:$F$11,MATCH(H2,$A$2:$A$11,0),MATCH(I2,$B$1:$F$1,0))`

First `MATCH` is for Height, second is for Length.

Sample image:

[image: Sample]

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ed16km08ikhh68f/LengthHeightMatch.xlsx

Comment: Just in case - values are randomly generated, only for the sample.